# How to disable editing in a cell according to the value in another cell in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a requirement where I need to only ask  the user for a flag and if that flag is true, I need him to input a number in another cell in that row. 
If it's false then that cell should be un-editable.
I know how to put restrictions on cells but I have no idea about this kind of conditional restrictions. 
[image]

Comment: Are the flags in column `A` already present at the time `apache poi` is parsing the sheet? If so, then the [CellStyle.setLocked](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setLocked-boolean-) could be set to `False` if there is `True`in column `A`. So if the sheet is protected, those cells will be not locked. But if not, then only data validation is possibly which checks whether `A` is true when `B` gets a value and alerts if not. Please clarify.

Comment: I am sorry. I think you misunderstood me. I want this to happen when the user is filling the sheet. As in, when he fills True in the first column, second column should become editable but if not then it will be uneditable. 
I need to somehow create this rule while creating the sheet.

Comment: This sounds more like an Excel issue rather than a POI issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  the flags in column `A` would be already present at the time `apache poi` is parsing the sheet, then the [CellStyle.setLocked](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setLocked-boolean-) could be set to `False` if there is `True` in column `A`. So if the sheet is protected, those cells will be not locked and be editable.

But if the `True` or `False` in column `A` will be changed in `Excel` GUI, then this is not possible since it will not conditional changing while changing the value in column `A`. For this there would must be a possibility for conditional formatting the cells locking. But this possibility does not exists, at least not without using `VBA`.

Then only data validation is possible which checks whether `A` is true when `B` gets a value and alerts if not. [Data Validations](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation) are possible to set using `apache poi`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;

public class CreateExcelDataValidationIfATrueThenB {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createCustomConstraint("AND(A1, B1<>\"\")");

  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(-1, -1, 1, 1);
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);

  validation.createPromptBox("For column B:", "If column A is True, then please put content in column B, else not.");
  validation.setShowPromptBox(true);
  validation.createErrorBox("Bad Value", "Please put content in column B only if column A is True, else not!");
  validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(true);
  sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(false);
  sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue(false);
  sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue(true);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationIfATrueThenB.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

As said above, conditional formatting the cells locking would be possible using `VBA` events while changing the cells in column `A`. But `apache poi` not provides creating `VBA` code. So if this would be the requirement, then a `Excel` template must be used which contains those macros already.

Comment: Hi Axel, That works beautifully. Although, I didn't understand where exactly did you set the rule to check the value in A. I am guessing it is the dvHelper.creteCustomConstraint("AND(A1, B1<>\"\")") 
But I do not understand that expression. Can you please point me towards a source where I can read up on this formula?

Comment: The constraint `AND(A1, B1<>"")` is true if `A1` is true and `B1` is not empty (not equals an empty string). Applied to the whole column `B` it checks not only `A1`and `B1` but `A1`, `A2`, ... `A1048576` and `B1`, `B2`, ... `B1048576` because there is not a `$` in `A$1` and `B$1`. But this is `Excel` knowledge and not programming related.

Comment: That makes sense and should've been something I should be able to think myself. Thank you.